# maximum possible number for a XMM register

Tags: intel, sse

One doubt. I saw that the 128-bit xmm registers support a minimum of two double-precision floating point 64-bit numbers. In Intel Manual says that the max number is 1.79 × 10<sup>308</sup>, but I do not know how to organize the content in response to:

1. 1 bit sign.
2. 11 bits biased exponent.
3. 52 bits significand fraction.

Comment: It's just two separate IEEE-754 double precision (64 bit) values - what specific problem are you trying to solve ?

Comment: I do not know how to express the numbers

Comment: They are just the same as C or C++ `double` - you can express them any way you like, e.g. `1.0`, `1.23456e42`, etc.